# I am getting this Error: Invalid URI "mycompany.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/get_cases/39" when integrating with cucumber -supertest

Tags: javascript, cucumber, supertest, testrail

When I get **mycompany.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/get_cases/39** in browser I do get a json response with all the needed detail.

When I give the same in terminal with curl (not very knowledgeable in curl) I get:

```
`>> curl mycompany.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/get_cases/39
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
</body>
</html>`
```

and in browser I am getting all the response.

I suspect this has to do something with authorization:

```
const TestRail = require('testrail-api');
const config = require('../../cucumber/support/config.json');

const testRail = new TestRail({
  host: config.testRail.host,
  user: config.testRail.user,
  password: config.testRail.apiKey
});


function getAlltestCases(projectid){
  testRail.getCases(projectid,function (err, response, cases) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(err);
  console.log(cases);
  });
}
module.exports = getAlltestCases;
```

where the config files do contain my testrailapikey generated in testrail with name supertest -(suspicious!? Because. My newman code only successed after creating the key as 'Newman')

in the format

```
`username - mytestrail@email.com
apikey -mysecretapikeyfromtestrail.io
my domain - mycompany.testrail.io`
```

and step definition as

```
...
Then('get all test cases', function () {
    const projectid = 39
    console.log("this worked?")
    getAlltestCases(projectid);

});
```

called in BDD as

```
...
Then get all test cases
```

... And when call the `npm run test`

I am getting this in console.

[image: tesrail api integration error invalid uri]

Comment: What if you do `curl -L` to follow redirections?

Comment: @GaëlJ when I added -L it showed
{"error":"Authentication failed: invalid or missing user\/password or session cookie."}

Comment: Well anyway, the issue your with code is elsewhere. You actually have 2 errors: one Cucumber step is not defined (yellow in screenshot), and one generated an error as URI is not valid but you don't show the code you're using so we cannot help more.

Comment: I think there are two issues: 1 - as @GaëlJ mentioned - you need to use `-L` when using cURL,  
2 - you have malformed URL in TestRail object - add `https://` in the beginning

Comment: Thank you guys, I got the answer. It was simply the missing https as @Sergi mentioned. I actually saw one document say that to not to use the protocol in URL when implementing testrail. Gaël J, your point on curl was actual too. But my issue was in the code, and the curl was just for testing purposes. if you can add this as an answer, I can approve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a malformed URL in TestRail object, add `https://` in the beginning to fix it